How to Configure CI/CD Pipeline to Pull Changes Using SSH Key or Access Token Without Username and Password?
I am in the process of setting up a CI/CD pipeline and need some guidance on configuring my script to automatically pull changes from a target branch. I would like to achieve this without the need to input a username and password. Instead, I want to use either an SSH key or an access token to authenticate and pull the changes.
Here is a brief overview of what I'm trying to accomplish:
Environment: I have a script within a CI/CD pipeline that needs to pull the latest changes from a specific branch in a GitHub repository.
Authentication: I want to avoid using a username and password for authentication. Instead, I prefer to use an SSH key or a GitHub access token to authenticate the script.
Configuration: I need guidance on how to configure the GitHub repository and the script to use the SSH key or access token for seamless authentication and pulling of changes.
Could someone provide a step-by-step guide or point me to relevant documentation on how to set this up? Specifically, I'm looking for:

Instructions on generating and adding an SSH key to the GitHub repository.

How to configure the CI/CD pipeline script to use the SSH key or access token for authentication.

Any best practices or tips for securely managing the SSH key or access token within the pipeline.



#1 Before to use any ci/cd tool or automation, you should know how to do it manually. #2 Do you know how to clone a github repository with ssh instead user/password? #3 What ci/cd tool are you using? #4 What os are you using #5 If you don't share (source code) your attempt or progress, it could seem like you want a full answer to your homework or job requirement. This could end with downvotes

Yes, I know how to clone a github repository with ssh instead user/password and I'm using Linux, I don't want a full answer to your homework or job requirement I only want to know how to pull without username and password  only with ssh or access token.

#0 Are you using a bash script? or some yaml steps like gitlab, github action, bitbucket pipeles, etc? #1 If you already know how to clone with ssh, why not to put that steps in your  script? #2 I'm here to help you, not to judging you :b

@JRichardsz I'm using github action for this, I want to take pull from the branch with SSH and access token which will set one time, but it's asking for username and password to take pull from the branch.

Is the repo you want to pull the changes from a different repo than the one where your workflow is running?

@BenjaminW. No it's the same repo i want to take pull from, but now it's asking for username and password but i want to take this from SSH and access token. and i want to set only for one time then after whenever i take pull it doen't ask for anything I want ti set this in my script .

The repository that hosts the workflow is accessible with GITHUB_TOKEN, the built-in short-lived token that is provided for each workflow run. You might have to explicitly set permissions for contents: read, but no extra authentication is required. It would be helpful if you provided a [mcve].
